# Onchange of Textbox Jquery AutoComplete Combobox value to blank

Tags: javascript

I am having two drop downs, one is with jquery auto complete combobox and another with normal drop down.Here i have to make the option value of jquery auto complete combobox to be blank onchange of normal drop down if the option value of combobox is already selected in javascript.Can u please help me on this

Comment: If u show some code, it will be easier to make some suggestions...else try to bind the change event to the 2nd drop down and make the 1st one blank..

Answer (score 0):

Call onChange event on Select element, write a javascript function which blanks the autotext box value

```
Example :  
       $("#txtWeight").val() = "";
```